# Moving UITableViewCell between Two Section ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using two section like, 
Section 1 with 
    cell 0
    cell 1 
    cell 3  and
Section 2 with
    cell 0
    cell 1
    cell 3

but i want to move cell 0 of section 2 in section 1 
can any one explain me with code using swift programming

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: You can just swap values in your data source and reload the table

Comment: exactally, but can you please explain me with code buz i am new in ios development

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to understand that the data source needs to be updated **before** the cells get swapped otherwise you have a crash.

Look at the following example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var data : [[String]] = [["Mike", "John", "Jane"], ["Phil", "Tania", "Monica"]]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data[section].count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
        let name = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        (cell.viewWithTag(22) as UILabel).text = "(" + String(indexPath.section) + ":" + String(indexPath.item) + ") " + name

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func pressed(sender: UIButton) {

        // arbitrarily define two indexPaths for testing purposes
        let fromIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        let toIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)

        // swap the data between the 2 (internal) arrays
        let dataPiece = data[fromIndexPath.section][fromIndexPath.row]
        data[toIndexPath.section].insert(dataPiece, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)
        data[fromIndexPath.section].removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)

        // Do the move between the table view rows
        self.tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(fromIndexPath, toIndexPath: toIndexPath)


    }
}
```

Here I have the simplest case of a 2-d Array which holds some names. I define it as [[String]] to avoid casting it later. Before the In my Storyboard I have a button which calls 'pressed'. I swap the data source and then call moveRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Hi Possible can I ask question related to `moveRow` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 2), toIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1))
```

Just don't forget to update your data model **before** calling this method.